# CRON Expression for month end, but it should not work if the last day of the Month is Friday

Tags: cron, scheduler, job-scheduling, uipath-orchestrator

I'm working on the UIpath Orchestrator where I need to put a custom scheduler for a job,
here is the cron expression which I written 0 0 5 L * ? * , it works fine and run's every last day of the month but now I want to change this expression that will work only if the last working day is not Friday.

Answer (score 0):

0 0 0 L * ? * (Last day of each month)

0 0 0 LW * ? (Last weekday of each month)

I don't think Orchestrator allows you to actually write the days in your expression (not sure on the specifics unfortunately)
But you could always go update your Non-Working Days calender and apply to the calendar to the process trigger.

This website is a useful generator from the CRON expressions and has alot of examples at the bottom https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html
[enter link description here](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)